# bin/console missing after running composer install

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

Hoping someone could help me out with this one please.

My project (on github https://github.com/irvingswiftj/iceMarkt ) when running composer install, seems to run without a hitch, until running the post update commands. In which I end up with the following error (when adding param -vvv):

```
    Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
    Could not open input file: bin/console
    Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception

    [RuntimeException]                                                         
    An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.
```

If I now browse my project directory, I can see that bin/console is never created!

Comment: Are you using a Symfony3 structure ? The `app/console` was moved to `bin/console` in this new structure. So look if you have a `app/console`... And AFAIK, there is an option that tell composer which structure you are using

Comment: yes, I am using the symfony3 structure. I didn't check for an app/console, but that didn't exist either.

Comment: I suspect you never checked in the bin directory to github?  Your best bet would probably be to make a new project using the s3 structure then compare the file systems.  You might be missing more than the bin directory.  I don't see a web directory either in github.

Comment: Then, as you're using the Sf3 structure, do you have the symfony-var-dir directive in your extra config in your composer ?

Comment: Cerad, you were right, I forgot to commit the bin dir, I had just assumed that doing a composer install would even create the console file

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had deleted the bin directory assuming that the executable console file would be created in my next composer install. I was wrong! Don't gitignore your bin/composer file and also make sure that if you are using the symfony 3 folder structure, you don't have .gitignore for the symfony 2 folder structure.

Comment: Looks like the only way to get the bin/console file back is to copy it from a new directory. Please let me know if you find a way to trick Symfony3 into recreating it... I find this silly.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem because I was accostumed to add the *bin* directory to my .gitignore file, because in Symfony2 all bin files (including the ones from other vendors) where placed in that folder, but that is not the case in Symfony3, so we can add the bin directory to our code repositories.

You can solve problem installing a new application (using the symfony installer) and copying the bin directory from this new project to your own project.

Answer (score 4):

Using Symfony 4 / Symfony Flex, you need to install the `symfony/console` package:

```
composer require symfony/console
```

Then use from your project dir:

```
./bin/console
```

As the file itself is starting with a shebang `#!/usr/bin/env php` you can execute it right away without `php` infront.

Comment: To add to this answer, if after requiring the `symfony/console` package the script is still not present, it must be because the script is auto generated on `composer install`. So you need to delete your `vendor` folder and run `composer install`. After that the `bin/console` script should be present

Answer (score 0):

With newer versions of Symfony and Flex installed,

```
composer --force recipes:install symfony/console
```

This will bring bin/console into existence.
If it's already there but you need to update it, use

```
composer recipes:update symfony/console
```

```
composer recipes
```

Just lists your recipes.