# Composer misses to install certain files (app/console, AutoLoader.php, app_dev.php, etc.)

Tags: symfony, composer-php, upgrade, directory-structure

I am developing a web application with Symfony 2. The code of my own bundle that forms the heart of my application and some configurations files for application-wide settings are controlled by Git (mostly the directories, `src/MyCompany/MyBundle`, `app/Resources/config`, etc.) The rest is under control of Composer (the framework, 3rd party bundles, etc.)

Up to now, I ran a `./composer self-update && ./composer.phar update` once in a while, pushed or fetched source code from the origin of my repository and everything has been working well.

Today, I started a new fresh working directory and experienced some odd problems.

I performed

```
git clone <my git repo url> www
cd www
composer.phar install
```

The `composer.json` is part of my repository, hence it normally suffices to excute Composer in order to install the framework and all required bundles to get a fully working copy of my web application.

But today, `composer.phar install` stopped prematurely complainig about missing files. Luckily, I still had my old working directory, so I could copy over the missing files manually, and restart `composer.phar`. I had to repeat these steps several times until I ended with a fully working application.

The files that were missing are

- `app/console`
- `AutoLoader.php`
- `app_dev.php`
- `AppCache.php`

I thought that these files are part of the Symfony framework and expected them to be installed by Composer. Fot this reason they are not under control of my revision control system.

I found this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530432). The answer is very generic und not particularly helpful. All it says is that for example `app/console` should be included into revision control, because it is not installed by Composer (any longer) and that there is a change in the directory structure due to the transition from Symfony 2 to 3. But I know for sure that `app/console` was installed by Composer in the past. Hence, something changed.

This leads me to the following questions

1. Is there any *complete, up-to-date and official* documentation

   1. what should be included in the repository
   2. what should be in `.gitignore`
   3. what is managed by Composer?
2. Is there any documentation how to do the transistion from the old directory structure to the new one in preperation of Symfony 3?

I thought I read all `README.md`, all release information and everything in "Living on the Edge" of the Symfony site, but somehow I missed this.

Answer (score 0):

The clean way to install Symfony2 from scratch with composer, is to use the [following command](https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#creating-a-symfony-application-with-composer):

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name
```

This will ensure that all basic structures are created. After that, you can still insert your customisations from the previous project.

Then you can add everything – except `app/config/parameters.yml` as well as the contents of `vendor/`, `app/cache` and `app/logs` – to your repository.

About transitioning to SF3, I guess there’ll be an upgrade path as soon as SF3 is stable enough to create such a document.

Answer (score 0):

1.1. that depends how you want people to be able to fetch your bundle

1.2. I share with you my own .gitignore: beware I use git for my own use to have a security for my files, not to allow people to get my bundle:

```
    # Cache and logs (Symfony2)
/app/cache/*
/app/logs/*
!app/cache/.gitkeep
!app/logs/.gitkeep
# Cache and logs (Symfony3)
/var/cache/*
/var/logs/*
!var/cache/.gitkeep
!var/logs/.gitkeep
# Parameters
/app/config/parameters.yml
/app/config/parameters.ini
# Managed by Composer
/app/bootstrap.php.cache
/var/bootstrap.php.cache
/bin/*
!bin/console
!bin/symfony_requirements
/vendor/
# Assets and user uploads
/web/bundles/
/web/uploads/
# PHPUnit
/app/phpunit.xml
/phpunit.xml
# Build data
/build/
# Composer PHAR
```

1.3. everything that is in composer.json